# Installing JAVA 8: Unable to locate package

Tags: apt, java, sudo, repository, add-apt-repository

I am trying to install java 8 and I get the following error:

```
root@usr:~# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

After making some research i typed the following solution:

```
root@usr:~# sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

But i get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python-software-properties is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsolete, or is only available from another source

E:Unable to locate package software-properties-common
E:Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate
```

After this i tried:

```
root@usr:~# sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

and i get the following error message:

```
E:Unable to locate package software-properties-common
```

I don't know what else to do. Can you help please ?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: just issue     sudo apt-get update    than retry that last install command

Comment: I suspect you're not using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

how to install latest java JDK and JRE

download both java jdk and jre from

```
    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

expand into home dir :

```
    ~/jdk*
    ~/jre*
```

once both directories are temporarily in your home dir just cut and paste all of below into a terminal

```
# ............ TOP of cut N paste >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  #

sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java

cd /usr/local/java

#   remove previous installs if any

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/java/jdk*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/java/jre*

#   move downloaded into /usr/local/java

sudo mv ~/jdk* /usr/local/java/
sudo mv ~/jre* /usr/local/java/

cd /usr/local/java/

#   create symbolic links

sudo ln -s jdk*  jdk
sudo ln -s jre*  jre

#   ___ ONLY need to do below on fresh ubuntu install - not necessary if previously installed any java version as its already in place
# symlinks :

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jre/bin/java" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk/bin/javac" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jre/bin/javaws" 1

sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jre/bin/java

sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk/bin/javac

sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jre/bin/javaws

java -version   #  run this to verify install worked

# ............ BOTTOM of cut N paste >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  #
```

done ... confirm all is well by issuing

```
java -version
```

which should give you similar to

```
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```